# AndroidViewModel does not preserve state between Fragment switch

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I was under the impression, that a ViewModel would preserve state and data between Fragment switches, as long as they belong to the same Activity. That does not seem to be the case.

My ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        Log.d("MainViewModel","constructor called");
    }
}
```

Access in a fragment:

```
MainViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
```

I noticed that the constructor is called every time I request the ViewModel. I thought that the purpose of the ViewModel was to stay alive all this time and could be used to preserve some state between fragments. Am I doing this wrong? Was my expectation wrong? How can I preserve state between fragments?

Comment: "ViewModel would preserve state and data between Fragment switches" - it does do that, but it depends on how you switch fragments. You haven't shown any of that code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a `ViewModelProvider` that is scoped to the fragment instance rather than the parent activity instance. Replace `new ViewModelProvider(this)` with `new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())`.

More info available in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-apis#vm-api-any-owner